# Will Apple accept apps built only with Xcode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, xcode4.5, appstore-approval

I am doing one application in Xcode 4.5. Just yesterday I heard that Apple will reject the builds which are created below Xcode 5, and which are not supporting iOS 7. Is this information accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. Apple will not approve apps that are compiled with Xcode versions below 5.0.

Comment: Can i build my xcode 4.5 project with xcode 5 and submit to apple?

Comment: yeah you can code with xcode 4.5 and have to submit with xcode 5

Comment: Not mandatory,but you have make sure your UI is suitable for iOS7 also.Because most users using iOS7 only

Comment: @user3146380 Just use XCode 5 and open your project and run it. (keep a backup). Most probably your app will work fine on iOS 7. If your app does not run as expected , you have to fix those issues. That's what we call updating to iOS 7.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Apple now only accepts builds from Xcode5. This is applicable since 1st Feb, 2014.

Here is the link:https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a

So, your build should be compiled from Xcode5 for submission on App Store, otherwise Apple rejects your App.

Comment: actually app won't get rejected, because apple will not even let you submit an app which is not compiled with XCode 5. It won't pass the validation test when submitting.

Comment: Very confusing.Please clarify me reject or not?

Comment: Since 1st feb,2014. you have to compile your build using Xcode5, otherwise Apple not allow you to send them build compiled with less version of Xcode5.

Comment: its depend upon you that which iOS you want to target.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  As per [this Apple announcement](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172013a), as of 2014-Feb-01, a developer can only submit apps built using Xcode 5.x (or presumably later versions).  Lesser builds won't pass validation during an attempt to submit them.

**And** Xcode 5 only supports building apps using the iOS 7 SDK.  Use of any lower SDK with Xcode 5 is unsupported, and apps built with such also can't be submitted.  You can set a lower Deployment Target for your app, such as iOS 5.1 or 6.0, **if** your app supports not only iOS 7, but those lower versions as well.  But one should do this only if you test the app on actual devices running all the iOS versions claimed, as using only the iPhone Simulator is not a thorough OS compatibility test.

Note that it is likely that one will have to modify an older app when building it with the iOS 7 SDK, as several of the UI control metrics and default window/view positions have been changed from iOS 6 and earlier SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is exactly what Apple does. You should have received at least one mail to your developer account as well with that information.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,Apple will not accept app created below xcode5. From 1 feb, new apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode (Xcode5) and must be optimized for iOS 7.